# Sending mongo vars to Mail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

I'm trying to send vars to e-mail with `Node.js` via `nodemailer`:
I got this `mongo` vars:

```
const tmin = await regla.findOne({},{tmax:1,_id:0}); 
const tmax = await regla.findOne({},{tmax:1,_id:0});
const tmsj = await regla.findOne({},{tmsj:1,_id:0});
```

And I send this some like this:

```
sendMail(html: "Temp :"+{tmin:tmin.tmin});
```

But in the `inbox` I recive just: `**Temp : [object Object]**

How to convert this object to `string` o other legible vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First you must limit to one:

```
const tmin = await regla.find({},{tmax:1,_id:0}).limit(1);
const tmax = await regla.find({},{tmax:1,_id:0}).limit(1);
const tmsj = await regla.find({},{tmsj:1,_id:0}).limit(1);
```

2.Then acces to the *first* element of the `array`:

`sendMail(html: "Temp :"+{tmin[0].tmin});`